# My sub folder is not working after modifying .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have recently upgraded to SSL certificate and overwrites the **.htaccess** file with fallowing code

the code the code is look like this

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} parisakam\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://parisakam.com/$1 [R,L]
```

the website is a online shopping website, i cant access any sub folders.How can i short out this problem ?

Comment: What is your htaccess supposed to do?

Comment: it will redirect to sub folder. @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: You will need to add more information to the question. Currently your question is extremely vague. We cannot _guess_ what the specific issue is. What does "is not working" actually mean? What does your http servers error log file show? What do you see in your browser? In your browsers development console?

Comment: Most likely you have absolute references in your website to the http version of your site which means that you will try to load insecure content from a secure page which is prevented by every sane browser. But that is something you should clearly see, yet you did not tell us.